# My OG video embed tags stopped working

Tags: facebook, video, embed, playback

I've racked my brain - used the Lint - debugger and still cannot get embeded video to work like it used to:

Example page:

http://www.mixtubedj.com/view/?query=GeorgeRon&file=GeorgeRon_20120802220844.flv

It shows the image, and shows everything right but i cannot get embed play to work again!

It says there is an error in the redirect but i don't see where. Can i get a second set of eyes?

Comment: It appears to be erroring on this part:

if i change 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mixtubedj.com/streams/" />

to 

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mixtubedj.com/" />

The errors go away but doesn't read the thumbnail information and uses default pictures - and again does not place a 'play' button on the window to watch embeded.